# with-slots with defstruct "class" instance

Tags: cl-lib, eieio, defstruct

Is it possible to use a `with-slots`-type macro with an instance of a defstruct-defined class in emacs lisp? I tried and I'm getting this error:

```
eieio-oset: Wrong type argument: eieio-object, "some-string", obj.
```

Sample code:

```
(progn
  (defstruct testobj a b)
  (require 'eieio)
  (with-slots (a b)  (make-testobj :a 1 :b 2)
    (message "value: %s:"  (list a b))))
```

Answer (score 3):

While waiting for a better answer, I wrote a `with-slots` macro that seems to work with `defstruct` instances:

```
(defmacro my-with-slots (class-name slots obj &rest body)
  "Bind slot names SLOTS in an instance OBJ of class CLASS-NAME, and execute BODY."
  (declare (indent 3))
  `(cl-symbol-macrolet
       ,(cl-loop for slot in slots
                 collect `(,slot (cl-struct-slot-value ',class-name ',slot ,obj)))
     ,@body))
```

Comment: Instead of the `intern` which will fail if the defstruct specifies a different prefix, you can use `cl-struct-slot-value`.  As you found out, currently, `slot-value` and `with-slots` are specific to EIEIO and only work on EIEIO objects.

Comment: Thanks, edited answer.